# Cant able to install R package 'dplyr' in windows 8 os

Tags: r, rstudio

```
> install.packages("dplyr")
```

below error message is throwing in case of package install . I am trying via R stdio and R console and from both cases faces this problem. Moreover i changed the global option "use internet explorer library/proxy for HTTP"

```
              cannot open URL 'http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
            Installing package into ‘C:/Users/User/Documents/R/win-library/3.3’
            (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
            Warning in install.packages :
              InternetOpenUrl failed: ' âŽˆÿ'
            Warning in install.packages :
              InternetOpenUrl failed: ' âŽˆÿ'
            Warning in install.packages :
              unable to access index for repository http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
              cannot open URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
            Warning in install.packages :
              InternetOpenUrl failed: ' âŽˆÿ'
            Warning in install.packages :
              InternetOpenUrl failed: ' âŽˆÿ'
            Warning in install.packages :
              unable to access index for repository http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/src/contrib:
              cannot open URL 'http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
            Warning in install.packages :
              package ‘dplyr’ is not available (for R version 3.3.3)
            Warning in install.packages :
              InternetOpenUrl failed: ' âŽˆÿ'
            Warning in install.packages :
              InternetOpenUrl failed: ' âŽˆÿ'
            Warning in install.packages :
              unable to access index for repository http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3:
              cannot open URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/PACKAGES'
            Warning in install.packages :
              InternetOpenUrl failed: ' âŽˆÿ'
            Warning in install.packages :
              InternetOpenUrl failed: ' âŽˆÿ'
            Warning in install.packages :
              unable to access index for repository http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/3.3:
              cannot open URL 'http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/PACKAGES'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finall i have solved this problem by using the default download method to "libcurl"

```
options(download.file.method="libcurl")
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this similar problem that you are facing now. The problem started when I tried to install an upgraded version (3.2.5). I applied a combination of tricks. But I think changing the repos with the following worked for me. Give it a try.

1. Give R and RStudio administrative privilege >> "run as administrator"

   ```
    - Or, Permanently Change: Using properties and Compatibility
   ```
2. Uncheck "use internet explorer library/proxy for HTTP" in RStudio and Restart.

Not necessary:

3. If you wish to change repos:

   `install.packages("dplyr", dependencies=TRUE, repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')`

*I am using RStudio Version 0.99.491
R version 3.2.5 (2016-04-14)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7600)*

Comment: Hello @Akash Ansari I have done all the things that you mentioned and still i am facing the same problem: R version 3.3.3 R stduio Version 1.0.136

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin this is really confusing. I have never figured out what is the actual reason behind this. I searched over the internet quite a few times. But I have not found any single solid reason. I guess, the problem is due to RStudio. But the irony is that we can not think of R without RStudio. So what can we do now at this moment?


1) While waiting here, post this problem at 
https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us


2) If these don't work, try reinstalling R & RStudio with different versions.


_(Please let me know if you have found out the reason behind this problem)_